# Files I should have on every website

Tags: robots.txt, 404, logging, favicon

I would like to have a list of files that should exist on every website. The idea is to please most browsers and bots and get down with the number of 404 messages in the logs.

So far I have the following files:

- `/favicon.ico`
- `/robots.txt`
- `/sitemap.xml`
- `/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon.png`

Are there other files that get requested often and should be on every website?

Comment: I just hate those! WTF are they thinking? If I wanted them to use it I would have added them...

Comment: I understand you... But what I hate even more are 404 messages in my apache log.

Comment: to be clear. What I hate is that user-agents tries to access them by default.

Comment: This begs a different question though. It seems like your primary concern is to reduce "extraneous" 404 logs. Are you getting a lot of legitimate 404 logs that you need to sort through? Or are you trying to sort through the log for other errors and the 404's are getting in the way?

Comment: @Chris: What I try to achieve is to have some kind of checklist of what I and my employees should think of when we work in a new project. It is just that we always forget some of these and I would like to set some standards on what we will do and what not. Often small details can make a difference. And yes, I had the situation once that a website was running for several years and then I had looks through the log files and find some error messages. But in this case I have other ways. I can use grep etc. The 404 messages are not that annoying then.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Sorry, I didn't understand you correctly. Now it is clear. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a problem with browsers looking for site icons automatically, as that saves webmasters the need to include a reference to them on every single page. However, I do wish Apple would have stuck with the favicon standard, which supports alpha channels as well as multiple icon sizes.

Comment: 404's are expected to be honest and 404's are not a negative thing. It's completely acceptable to have 404's and if your worried about them filling your logs then just phrase the data into a single 404 file and then filter though using keyword filtering.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know, no bots or apps request *sitemap.xml* without being told it should be there. Most sites probably don't have it, and of the sites that do, many use gzip, and many call the file something else or put the sitemaps in a subfolder.

Here are all the ones I know of:

- ***favicon.ico***
  Gives your pages an icon in tabs, bookmarks, etc.
- ***robots.txt***
  Useful if you need to block any pages from search engines, but can be blank to allow access to everything. It can also contain the location for your sitemap.
- **Webmaster Tools verification files**
  The easiest method of verification (saves having useless meta tags in your HTML code). There's `google[hash].html` and `BingSiteAuth.xml`. I have one for Yahoo in my root too but that's probably no longer needed.
- ***crossdomain.xml***
  This file is requested by Adobe Flash any time Flash needs to connect to your site. You will probably never see this file in your logs on a small site, but I had a bunch of requests for it on one site. You can just create a blank file since the default is to block access to external sites.
- ***.htaccess*** (Apache)
  Obviously not requested by browsers/bots but vital for most sites.

Finally, regarding the icons that the iPhone insists on requesting: there are several sizes that may get requested. My iPhone 3G (iOS 5) requests the 57x57 version and I see 72x72 and 114x114 (most common) in my error logs. So if you want to eliminate all 404s from your logs, mind-boggingly you would need to provide all of these:

- `/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png`
- `/apple-touch-icon.png`

Comment: `.htaccess` is specific to Apache and, even for those using Apache, it is a [poor choice for performance](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html#htacess) if one has access to the VirtualHost definitions.

Comment: +1 for crossdomain.xml - that hadn't occurred to me, and is a great idea to include.

Comment: I had once a bot requesting the sitemap.xml about once a day. And I never registered this file somewhere. So this bot was just guessing it.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Thank you for the update. I didn't know that those other sizes exists too.

Comment: Silverlight also uses `clientaccesspolicy.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably have it.

Even apple touch icon is not entirely nescessary, since if you choose not to have it (and don't link to it) then iOS will just use a thumbnail of the page (personally, I add them in though).

I'd say you only really NEED *favicon.ico* and *robots.txt*, *sitemap.xml* is optional too.

Comment: This wouldn't prevent the request, and thus the 404 errors that Raffael is seeing in their logs. If you were going to concentrate on which files make the most impact, I'd say you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Another one that I've noticed is *browserconfig.xml* which is some bastardisation requested by IE. Bloody rubbish filling up the logs.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what should be in this file?

Answer (score 1):

Newer apple versions request these files (in this order)

- /apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png
- /apple-touch-icon-120x120.png
- /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
- /apple-touch-icon.png

Comment: Thanks. This would extend the list from DisgruntledGoat.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing these files why not 410 them?

Apache config:

```
Redirect    gone    "/favicon.ico"
Redirect    gone    "/sitemap.xml"
Redirect    gone    "/crossdomain.xml"
Redirect    gone    "/apple-touch-icon"
Redirect    gone    "/clientaccesspolicy.xml"
Redirect    gone    "/browserconfig.xml"
```

Comment: because we want to make as many devices as possible happy. The question is about giving the users the most comfort by providing the browsers whatever they need.

Comment: Many of them can be provided at alternate locations with link tag in the head.  Especially the favicon.ico.  Which is BTW on the way out being replaced by *.png.  This is 2020.  The some of the answers here are stale.